# Is it bad to create new worker threads every frame in a multi-threaded game?

Tags: c++, multithreading, game-engine

I have I've been experimenting with multi-threading a game engine. For sake of an example here is the basic structure of my code.

```
#include <thread>

int main() {

  std::thread physics_thread;
  std::thread particles_thread;
  std::thread graphics_thread;

  while (!shouldClose) {

    physics_thread   = thread(doPhysics,   &someData1);
    particles_thread = thread(doParticles, &someData2);
    graphics_thread  = thread(doGraphics,  &someData3);

    physics_thread.join();
    particles_thread.join();
    graphics_thread.join();

  }

}
```

Is this incredibly bad practice? I'm running linux on a pretty low-power system and creating these threads every update is quite cheap. In terms of all platforms though, is this just a bad idea?

On a side note I've tried to do constantly running worker threads with mutexs and condition variables out the wazoo and sometimes I can get it to work, but it seems absurdly complicated for what I'm trying to achieve.

Comment: Reallocating resources in the loop is definitely a bad practice. In this particular case you can utilize threadpool of some kind. However pointless reallocation is not the biggest issues with this snippet. Such loop puts strict synchronization of worker thread jobs instead of running them asynchronously.

Comment: Creating threads is expensive.

Comment: The complicated solution is bound to be a bit more efficient. It depends on your application if you really need that extra efficiency or not. Why not do some tests and see how much creating threads eats away your frame rate? Then decide if you need to create a more complex solution.

Comment: I can't really see why this would be a significant simplification over using constantly running threads. If your threads don't need to communicate with each other when you create/destroy them, why would making them keep running change that? And if they do need to communicate with each other, you still have to do that somehow.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Although this seems inexpensive, this is not the case.
Threads require some heavy lifting and if you know you are going to need them again (let alone reuse them multiple times) you should try and avoid it.

The classic solution is to use a thread pool to execute your tasks right when you need them, and then let the workers sleep until the next time.

The cost of having N additional sleeping threads is minimal and will not affect the application's performance.

Here is a simple yet very powerful single header [thread pool library](https://github.com/dtrugman/ThreadPool) I wrote.